# Why is this function causing a run time error

Tags: c, runtime

```
#include <stdio.h>


int fonction_test(void){
    static char index = 50;
    for(; index<=0xff;index++){
        printf("Valeur: %02x\r\n", index);
    }
    return (int(index));
}

int main(){
    // your code goes here
    fonction_test();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not that familiar with C to be honest but i would like to understand why is this iterating only 155 times.

Comment: 1) This isn't C. 2) Overflow occurs in `char` regardless of whether it is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: How exactly did you think `index` would ever become larger than `0xff`?

Comment: this line: `for(; index<=0xff;index++){` is always true.  the compiler will output a warning message (which seems to have been ignored) "warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-wtype-limits]"

Comment: the syntax for this line: `return (int(index));` is not correct and cause the compiler to output: "error: expected ')' before 'index'"   The line should have been: `return (int)index;`

Comment: why bother to have the return type for `fonction()` be `int` when the caller does not use the returned value.  Suggest 1) remove the `return` statement 2) use the signature: `void fonction_test( void )`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 2):

'index' is a `char`. As per C chars can be signed or unsigned. This is **implementation defined**. So it will be different for different compilers/ processors.

The maximum value that a `char` it can take is 255 (0xFF). When you add 1 the value it will take will depend on whether `char` is signed or unsigned in your system. If unsigned, it will loop to `0`. If signed, it is **undefined**, but most compilers will still wrap around to `-128`. In either case, the for loop condition will never be false.

You have an infinite loop. And that is why it seg faults.

Also, the code you have will not compile, you need to modify the line `return (int(index));` to `return ((int)(index));`